# amChart in AngularJS Legend's switchable propiety don´t work, attachent the code

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

This is my code, Legend's switchable property does not work, The graph has 3 linear series on two value axes, the idea is to hide the series(s) that are currently not useful.

You used the Akvio blur Admin temple, I followed the instructions, the bower file has all the dependencies of amChart. If I run the examples work very well, but they do not have the same structure as the angularJS handlers.

I have no idea what's failing or missing to set up.

I'll appreciate the help of everyone who can help me.

```
$scope.difference = response.data
var chart2 = AmCharts.makeChart('chartDiff', {
    type: 'serial',
    theme: 'blur',
    dataProvider: $scope.difference,
    balloon: {
            fillAlpha: 1,
            shadowAlfa: 0.5,
            showBullet: true
    },
    valueAxes: [
        {
        axisAlpha: 0,
        position: 'left',
        title: 'Revenue - Payroll',
        autoGridCount: true,
        unit: '$',
        unitPosition: 'left',
        id: 'Axis-1',
        color: '#2A0A12'
        },
        {
        axisAlpha: 0,
        position: 'right',
        title: 'Difference',
        autoGridCount: true,
        unit: '$',
        unitPosition: 'left',
        id: 'Axis-2',
        color: '#F0B71D'
        }
    ],
    graphs: [
        {
        balloonColor: '#35BC3F',
        balloonText: '',
        lineThickness: 2,
        fillColorsField: '#b52121',
        valueField: 'revenue',
        title: 'Revenues',
        switchable: true
        },
        {
        balloonColor: '#ff0000',
        balloonText: '',
        fillColorsField: '#b52121',
        lineThickness: 2,
        title: 'Payrolls',
        valueField: 'payroll',
        switchable: true
        },
        {
        balloonColor: '#ee0000',
        balloonText: '',
        fillColorsField: '#b55521',
        lineThickness: 2,
        title: 'Difference',
        valueField: 'difference',
        switchable: true,
        valueAxis: 'Axis-2'
        }
    ],
    chartCursor: {
        enabled: true,
        bulletsEnabled: true,
        categoryBalloonColor: "#F0D9A8",
        color: "#000000",
        cursorPosition: "mouse",
        graphBulletAlpha: 0,
        graphBulletSize: 5,
        selectionAlpha: 0.93,
        valueLineAlpha: 1,
        cursorColor: "#000000",
        valueLineEnabled: true
    },
    categoryField: 'driver_full_name',
    categoryAxis: {
        gridPosition: 'start',
        labelRotation: 30,
        autoWrap: true,
        fontSize: 8 
    },
    export: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        useGraphSettings: true,
        enabled: true,
        backgroundAlpha: 0,
        textClickEnabled: true,
        useMarkerColorForValues: true,
        useGraphSettings: true,
        color: '#4C4646',
        labelText: "[[title]]:",
        spacing: 40,
        valueAlign: 'left',
        valueText: "$[[value]]",
    }
});
```